# glutKeyboardfunc() callback function parameter

Tags: c++, opengl, callback

In a simple opengl program I have this line below :

```
glutKeyboardFunc(keypressed);
```

problem is  my "keypressed" function is in another cpp file included to project. How can I call this function from my other file ?

in main.cpp :

```
main()
{
  ---
  glutKeyboardFunc(keypressed);
  ---
}
```

in Motion.cpp :

```
void keypressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y){...}
```

Things I try (All gave compile error) :

```
glutKeyboardFunc(keypressed);
glutKeyboardFunc(Motion::keypressed);   
glutKeyboardFunc(&Motion::keypressed);
glutKeyboardFunc(&keypressed);  

Motion mot;
glutKeyboardFunc(mot.keypressed);
```

Any suggestions? 
(I used freeglut.dll if library matters for answer)

Comment: Make a `Motion.h` file which has a function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a function prototype somewhere where it will be read by your main C++ file. One way to do that would be to put this above your `main` function:

```
void keypressed(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
```

A common way to do this is to have each C++ file which exports functions also have a *header* file which includes prototypes for all those functions. Then, when you want to use a function defined within that file, you can include that header file at the top of the file that needs to use that function.

Comment: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl keypressed(unsigned char,int,int)" (?keypressed@@YAXEHH@Z) referenced in function _main  (I got this error when I add prototype of function to main.cpp)

Comment: @Cagkan: That means that each of your source files are successfully being compiled into object files, but when it comes time to link them together into an executable, only your main object file is being included. Since your main object file references that other object file that's not being included, you get an unresolved reference error. How to solve that depends on how you're compiling it.

Comment: thx for your helpfull answers.I am unfamiliar with visual studio c++ compiler :/. I will search compiling options of visual studio.